# SQL- Ensuring query does not include results where a certain column in null?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, timestamp

Below is the query I am using in order to check how many rows in my table have a date *older than* `01/01/2015 (TIMESTAMP).`

How can I alter this query to ensure that it *does not* include any results where the `DATE_INSERTED` column is `null`?

Also, if this is not the most *efficient* way to check for this condition, I would appreciate alternatives.

Current query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_INSERTED NOT BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015 00.00.00.00' AND '18-JAN-2016 00.00.00.00';
```

Comment: Have you tested your query with any null values?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry in v new to database development

Comment: Insert a null value into that column and test your query!

Comment: Surely there can just be an alteration to the query that ensures null vals are not returned?

Comment: `COUNT(DATE_INSERTED)` will not counts NULLs

Comment: @java123999 - what jarlh is saying that if you ran your query while the table had a null value you would see that it *already* excludes nulls. [A null is neither equal to nor not equal to anything](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/sql_elements005.htm), including another null; it is also therefore neither between nor not between any two values.

Comment: You'll be surprised how simple the answer is... But you still need to verify all answers you get here by yourself. (And also test your own queries, with all kind of data.)

Comment: Ok, does the query do this by default?

Comment: Yes, it does exclude null's. (Just as Alex Poole already has said.)

Comment: Is this the most efficient way of writing the query? All I want to check is for the amount of rows with a date before 1/1/2015? I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `is not null`
Here's your query updated:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_INSERTED
    NOT BETWEEN '01-JAN-2015 00.00.00.00' AND '18-JAN-2016 00.00.00.00'
    AND DATE_INSERTED is not null;
```

New line spacing is optional. Although it may look misleading by having: between param1 and param2 and column is not null... the first where condition you set (between) only takes two parameters, so the next AND is treated as default. Whereas the first is the separation between the first and second BETWEEN params.

Comment: Thanks, however in the above comments a few people have said that nulls are excluded by default?